# onInfoWindowClick don't work. But Long click works fine

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, onclicklistener

I've added two listeners to my map:

```
mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowLongClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, marker.getTitle() + " Long click");
    }
});

mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d(TAG, marker.getTitle() + " Just a simple click");
    }
});
```

And according to logcat long click works fine, but common click don't

```
2020-05-24 22:49:51.838 7940-7940/com.edwin.findme D/UserListFragment: test Long click
2020-05-24 22:49:53.309 7940-7940/com.edwin.findme D/UserListFragment: test Long click
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

UPD: Actually I need only click listener, but it's not working so I've added long click listener to test and it works fine.

Comment: Tried to replicate your issue however, both long click and the ordinary click listeners worked in my case. I've just added these methods under ```onMapReady()```. Can you please provide a [small reproducible sample](http://sscce.org) that shows your issue?

Comment: Nvm, I've found the solution. New versions of android-maps-utils requires to use MarkerManager.Collection to set a listener. https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils#adding-a-custom-info-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of android-maps-utils (1.3.1 in my case) requires to use MarkerManager.Collection to set a listener.

Source:
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils#adding-a-custom-info-window

*New*

```
CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = // ...
OnInfoWindowClickListener listener = // ...

// Create a new Collection from a MarkerManager
MarkerManager markerManager = // ...
MarkerManager.Collection collection = markerManager.newCollection();

// Set InfoWindowAdapter and OnInfoWindowClickListener
collection.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
collection.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(listener);

// Alternatively, if you are using clustering
ClusterManager<ClusterItem> clusterManager = // ...
MarkerManager.Collection markerCollection = markerCollection.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
markerCollection.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(listener);
```

*Old*

```
CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = // ...
OnInfoWindowClickListener listener = // ...
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: You're a genius mate